# Float:left causing styling issues with other dividers

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a design project and I have three divs for three different products. I also have a payment method image div as well as a copyright div. The three product divs are floated to the left within their own wrapper allowing them to center and display correctly although this has lead to the copyright and payment method divs appearing in a different position as opposed to where they should be.

Fixed, thank you for your help!

Comment: where you want the copyright and payment method image to be?

Comment: It means you want copyright at right and paypal at the left? Am I right

Comment: The copyright div should be displaying below the three products in the center of the page and the PayPal below that in then center of the page as well :S

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `clear:both` to your CSS on an element after your floated list.

```
.copyright {
     ...
     clear:both;
}
```

Comment: are you sure this will resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```